# Expecting non-empty string for 'providerInvariantName' parameter error in c# application having access database

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

I have a C# application having Access .accdb as a Database. Connection String are Managed by App.Config. I had developed project in 64 bit machine and when I installed application 32 bit machine at the time of Database connection error pops up that "Expecting non-empty string for 'providerInvariantName' parameter".
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: show me your connection string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added following code in App.config file in :

```
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

And after that error disappears.

Answer (score 2):

It must be connection string in App.Config.

Check links:
[Entity Framework - Expecting non-empty string for 'providerInvariantName' parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599311/entity-framework-expecting-non-empty-string-for-providerinvariantname-parame)
http://forums.asp.net/t/1491467.aspx?Expecting+non+empty+string+for+providerInvariantName+parameter

It seems u need to check ProviderName  in connection string. It should be providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" (for Sql provider).